# React + axios interceptors: retry original request within component's context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

I'm learning React and I'm using `axios` and JWT for authentication. I have written an interceptor to refresh the token automatically:

```
privateAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    const { config, response } = error;
    const originalRequest = config;
    if (response?.status === 401) {
      apiProvider
        .refreshToken()
        .then(() => {
          let headers = getAuthHeaders();
          privateAxios.defaults.headers = headers;
          originalRequest.headers = headers;
          return privateAxios(originalRequest);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          logout();
          return Promise.reject(err);
        });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

On my component I have the following:

```
api.post(data)
  .then(() => {
    showSuccessFeedbackForm();
    reloadTable();
    handleClose();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    setAlertInfos({
      message: JSON.stringify(error.response.data),
      severity: "error",
    });
    setShowAlert(true);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
  });
```

My problem is that I want to continue with the component's normal "flow" (i.e., `showSuccessFeedbackForm()` and `reloadTable()` and `handleClose()`) if the token needed to be refreshed (when the code reaches `return privateAxios(originalRequest)`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should just have to `return` the `apiProvider.refreshToken()...` call. After `return privateAxios(originalRequest);` returns, then `return Promise.reject(error);` is executing which causes the front-end to receiving an rejection not a resolution.

Consider this intercepted error which **does not throw** an error to the frontend which still "resolves":

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    console.log("##### AXIOS ERROR #####");
    dispatch(increment());
  }
);
```

Simply changing it to this causes the front-end to catch an error which is what your code is essentially doing:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    console.log("##### AXIOS ERROR #####");
    return Promise.reject();
  }
);
```